# How to flash Acer Aspire 5541 BIOS with USB when LCD is not working?

Tags: laptop, bios, usb-flash-drive, lcd, acer-aspire

I want to flash my BIOS to see if it will fix my LCD problem (screen is just black when i turn the laptop on).

The BIOS update says:

```
[Fixed History]
1. Solve DVD can't be dislpayed in clone mode
2. Support Intel TJ85 CPU (need to corperate with KBC v1.33)
**3. Add a BIOS workaround to prevent LCD-no-display issue. (v1.16 fixed.)**

[SOP]
Directly run "bios.bat" batch file within the attached zip file under windows mode
```

How do i tell my USB drive to run bios.bat when i plug it in?

I have seen somewhere on the net, that i am supposed to hold down FN + ESC for a couple of seconds, when my laptop is turned off, and it will automatically boot up, and try to flash the BIOS from the files on the USB drive.

Comment: Have you tried hooking it up to an external monitor?